# google maps boundary borders of regions

Tags: javascript, google-maps, latitude-longitude, postal-code

This is more of a research question than a technical question.

First I need to be able to draw sections of the uk like in this example : (http://blog.codebrain.co.uk/posts/uk_postcode_selector/postcode_selector.html)

Is there anywhere that has lat / long co-ordinates of the boundaries?

Following on from that is there a way to see if a postcode or lat/long position is withing these boundaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use geocoding for postal codes. And for sections you can use his kmz file:
http://blog.codebrain.co.uk/posts/uk_postcode_selector/postcode_selector.kmz

Comment: So how does this script determine, when you click, which area you have clicked, i.e. Birmingham?

Comment: Actualy I think it will just get location lat and lng and it sends that to geolocation, then it returns all information about that place.